# VBA: Setting column range after finding column header

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to set a range for the second cell under the column header I am searching for to the bottom of the column.  I don't want to select the entire column, but just the used range starting from the second cell (not including the header).

I was able to write some code to find the header, but I'm having some issues converting the cell address (string) to a range and then selecting the used range for the rest of that column. Here is what I am so far:

```
Sub colRange()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim hostCellRange As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        Set cfind = .Find(What:="host", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
            hostCell = cfind.Address
            Set hostCellRange = ws.Range(hostCell)
        End If
    End With
End With


End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: will you have blank cells in your range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it will be

```
Option Explicit

Sub colRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim hostCellRange As Range, cfind As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set cfind = .Find(What:="host", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
                '~~> Find the column number
                lCol = cfind.Column
                '~~> Find the last row in that column
                lRow = ws.Range(Split(Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                '~~> Create the range
                Set hostCellRange = .Range(cfind.Offset(1, 0), cfind.Offset(lRow - 1, 0))
                Debug.Print hostCellRange.Address
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Example 1**

[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

[Interesting Read on how to find the last row correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: Hey Siddharth, thank you for taking the time to explain the code as well! I will be using this! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `hostCellRange` using the `Offset` from `cfind`, you don't need the `Address` for that.

```
If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
    Set hostCellRange = .Range(cfind.Offset(1, 0), cfind.End(xlDown))
End If
```

**Note**: `cfind.End(xlDown)` will work with range without empty cells in the middle.